# build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:

Tags: java, netbeans

Estou fazendo um projeto de faculdade, e toda classe que eu coloco para herdar da classe `Modelo`, eu recebo esses erros.

> /home/tavz-correia/NetBeansProjects/exercicio01/AcessoriosParaVeiculos/nbproject/build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> /home/tavz-correia/NetBeansProjects/exercicio01/AcessoriosParaVeiculos/nbproject/build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Classe `Modelo.java`:

```
package acessoriosveiculos;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

/**
 *
 * @author tavz-correia
 */
public class Modelo {

         private List<String> modelos;

    public Modelo() throws Exception{

        List<String> lista = ler("/home/tavz-correia/NetBeansProjects/exercicio01/AcessoriosVeiculos/src/acessoriosveiculos/ObjetosSerializados/Modelos.ser");
        this.setModelos(lista);
    }

    public List<String> getModelos() {
        return modelos;
    }

    public void setModelos(List<String> modelo) {
        this.modelos = modelo;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<String> ler(String caminho) throws Exception {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        FileReader arquivo = new FileReader("/home/tavz-correia/NetBeansProjects/exercicio01/AcessoriosVeiculos/src/acessoriosveiculos/ObjetosSerializados/Modelos.json");
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(arquivo);
        List<String> lista = (List<String>) jsonObject.get("modelos");

        return lista;
    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

[Isso daqui comecei a escrever como comentário, mas vi que talvez sirva como resposta].

Já vi o Netbeans dar uns bugs estranhos quando ele corrompe a cache dele. O Netbeans mantém uma cache de arquivos para que ele possa rastrear e desfazer alterações, além de indexar o conteúdo dos arquivos mais facilmente. Entretanto, de vez em quando ocorre de alguma coisa, de alguma forma misteriosa, zoar essa cache e então deixar o Netbeans maluco. Por vezes ele acaba conseguindo voltar ao normal sozinho, de uma forma tão misteriosa quanto a forma como ele zoou, mas de vez em quando não volta ao normal de jeito nenhum.

Na minha máquina, essa cache fica localizada em subpastas ocultas de sistema `C:\Users\<nome-do-usuário>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\var` e `C:\Users\<nome-do-usuário>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\`. Por vezes, eu tenho que fechar o Netbeans, limpar/apagar essas pasta, abrir o Netbeans de novo e reconfigurá-lo para que ele volte ao normal.

No seu caso, como você está usando Linux, a cache provavelmente vai estar em algum lugar dentro de `/home/etc`, eu acho.

Comment: Apagar tudo que contem na pasta netbeans dentro do .cache ?

Comment: É, pode tentar isso. Se quiser se certificar de não estar fazendo nenhuma besteira, apenas renomeeie ela para alguma outra coisa. Apagando-a de vez se estiver firme na decisão ou voltando ela para o nome antigo se achar que isso não vai ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso resolvi limpando todas as bibliotecas e reinserindo apenas algumas que o projeto necessitava.